# Type guard length of two types

Tags: typescript

Can I guard two array types through a condition involving the length of both? I have two array types, I wanted to make sure that they both have the same length.

I want to define the types of `MyFunction` and/or use a guard logic so that:

`function MyFunction(['foo', 'bar'], [1, 2])` -> OK

`function MyFunction(['foo', 'bar'], [1, 2, 3])` -> Not OK

Alternately I could change the function parameters to accept an object:

```
{
  param1: ...
  param2: ...
}
```

This was in fact what I tried:

```
interface TableData<NCols extends number> {
  header: string[] & { length: NCols },
  xs: number[] & { length: NCols },
  data: [DataCol, ...DataCol[]] & { length: NCols },
}
```

To clarify I want to get a warning at compile type for invalid function parameter.

Comment: Can you show some code you were trying?

Comment: Well I wanted to guard `TableHeader` and `TableRow` so that they have the same length.

`interface HeaderCol {
  label: string,
  xs: number,
}

type TableHeader = HeaderCol[]

type TableRow = (string | number)[]

type TableData = TableRow[]`

Comment: As described in [ask], please consider editing the question text itself to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the issue you're running into.  It's easy enough at *runtime* to make sure two arrays have the same length; if you're asking about having some guarantee from the *compiler*, it would be helpful to look at actual code trying to use two arrays where the compiler is either letting you do something it shouldn't or not letting you do something it should.  Otherwise this is somewhat hypothetical and you might not get answers relevant to your use case. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz you're right. I complemented the initial question with additional information.

Comment: As far as I can see the problem you're getting is that `NCols` is inferred as `number`, and then any array size match. There is a trick you can use to prevent dynamic array from being fed into your function. Give me a moment to update my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer. You're only missing the `as const` at the call site. As I mentioned, you can't do it unless the types of the objects you pass in have `const` length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to be sure of this at the type level is to restrict the arrays to [tuple](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) types, whose lengths are known [numeric literals](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types).  Here's one formulation:

```
function zip<
  T extends (number extends T['length'] ? never : readonly any[]),
  U extends { [K in keyof T]: any }
>(
  t: T | [never],
  u: U | [never]
) {
  return (t as T).map((x, i) => [x, u[i]]) as any as { [K in keyof T]: [T[K], U[K]] };
}
```

Here the `zip()` function takes two arguments.  The first is of some array type `T`.  (Note that `readonly any[]` is, confusingly, *less* restrictive than `any[]`) where the `length` is *not* allowed to be of the type `number`.  (Fixed-length tuples will have lengths *narrower* than `number`, not `number` itself.)  This will prevent you from passing in arrays of unknown length.  Note that the `t` argument is actually of type `T | [never]`.  Including that empty tuple union [hints the compiler to infer tuple types for array literals](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990).  Without it, `[1, 2, 3]` will be inferred as `number[]` instead of `[number, number, number]`.

The second argument is of type `U` which must be assignable to a [mapped tuple](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) on `T`.  This will ensure they have the same length. (The same `| [never]` trick works to infer tuples instead of arrays)

It returns another mapped tuple of the same length where each entry is a pair containing one element of each original array.  Note that once you have a zipped array you can use it anywhere you needed to ensure that the original arrays were of the same length; an `Array<[T, U]>` will definitely have exactly one `T` for each `U` and vice versa.

Let's see if it works:

```
const okay = zip([1, 2, 3], ["A", "B", "C"]);
// const okay: [[number, string], [number, string], [number, string]]
const bad1 = zip([1, 2], ["A", "B", "C"]); // error! 
// [string, string, string] is not assignable to [any, any]
const bad2 = zip([1, 2, 3, 4], ["A", "B", "C"]); // error!
// [string, string, string] is not assignable to [any, any, any, any]
const bad3 = zip([1, 2, 3], []); // error!

const numArr: number[] = [1, 2, 3]; 
const strArr: string[] = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
const bad4 = zip(numArr, strArr); // error!
// number[] is missing property 0 

console.log(JSON.stringify(zip([1, 2, 3], ["A", "B", "C"])));
// [[1,"A"],[2,"B"],[3,"C"]]
```

Looks good to me.

---

Note that this may really be a bit much to expect from the compiler, especially since you might be getting your two arrays from contexts in which it's implausible to expect them to be of tuple types.  Instead I'd suggest you consider allowing the compiler to accept all kinds of arrays and only enforce length equality at runtime; and use something like `zip()` to get the known-same-length version of the pair of arrays in question.  Like this:

```
  function zip<T, U>(t: readonly T[], u: readonly U[]): Array<[T, U]> | undefined {
    if (t.length !== u.length) return undefined;
    return t.map((x, i) => [x, u[i]]);
  }

  const okay = zip([1, 2, 3], ["A", "B", "C"]); // allowed
  if (!okay) {
    console.log("That was bad");
  } else {
    console.log(okay.map(([x, y]) => x.toFixed() + ":" + y.toLowerCase()).join("; "))
    // 1:a; 2:b; 3:c
  }

  const bad1 = zip([1, 2], ["A", "B", "C"]); // allowed
  if (!bad1) {
    console.log("That was bad");
    // That was bad
  } else {
    console.log(bad1.map(([x, y]) => x.toFixed() + ":" + y.toLowerCase()).join("; "))
  }
```

It's more permissive at compile time, but it requires fewer type system hoops to jump through.  You check for `undefined` to see if it failed, instead of expecting a compiler error.

---

Okay, hope one of those helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVArjANtJBvAUEkgGZrDwAuAlgPbBIBeVMAPIUakhAB4UTAATKEgAUwNGABGEAE5de-IagDaAcmzAA5hQAWqgLpIA-EmAQAbrKQAuJDIggBdTAE8kIYC+X6AlABp2IgBVeT5BYVwkZQBpJCp6AGsIFxpiVH1bDzcAX3YAPhFApApbFCQAHyizSxl9AI4kNFsQyuVq2X12Hzwi+wo0GXoRCndhFB8AOjAQGBERbj847oBePKiFxuUqfV9R9089yJi4xOTU9NtlFBi6pCCbw2yAbnZcpHZ4OigRmgSQN2WjGYImUAEZFgAmRYAZluygARABBeGLeEAIRRSHhAGF4b4XkQAPSEpCfYDfJC-f6XNoSaQyRbfGTxTRw8RSWSMijMrRsumcpBMlk7D5fEaSRygpCApizMGQuFIzHo5W4-FIYlcGQyGgyACE7yJJOUQq0XJ5mnNwriwmANBGICgUComlAkmwxRoUSyiyynSIZIpEoEEOlQLl4KQUKQ0MWABZFcjURjUWqfE8NSTZDr9exNSbuSyrWbBYXeTbTPbRs7XSB3cgKF7lD79i5fZ52y5-aSxUhg9Cw7KQZHo7DFt505mtTm9fhReSRuzEdrbOz6d4w-KozD9ASewvSzJlzJbKbNBvAQik1iU1jcaiACJ4veB8WOOOD4FL7Xm4+TzXZrqs5GqY-IyBuVDCGAkHOloSAwDqMCyBQbgAAzvPOUA0NgEyYDQmgiAAUgAygA8gAchMZ5UMQLgiEOW6jomyq3jieI+Bxe75vKSp1MoUIqnxsZsSKuT4KAkCwAgyAAEpkNQkAAKLAMQuqIJAwAjAQ7CkOQ1B0OGLAoIsQQFCUdgOE4wCuCotxNBZjjOG49y+LYx7-CwVwmfoayVGQAgQMQ8QQAIPQNDRogULh-DaDoSB6ssgJoNFWi6N0fQDPQ-mBcFAh7kQGWDMUUwzHMGxUCsazKBsaBbDs6avHOAa9lSALhsOkI7uOSrJqq7EZpqICYHhADuIXsBFIh6q13QEA0gbYRAuH4SI8IoDoIAjCNjp9o48INUQ2RcJgUDIHNHALTheEEa1JWzCCGxdpVSDcBMjYAGJUNwIUiN0ADUWLWPCSAAy4b00AAMjQY0yNijoQL9kwAFY0PEq0ZvtPhFJqoLWCAGYQtYkgZtC1jwI1mFvgIUoysCjHMb1qb9VOQ2jeNRCTXqwagrNRSXUt12retm1INtwjBvt+VTsLW07cGrzHadYUXV8i3LQR3N3XM1WLE90prK9H1fT9-2A8DoPg1DMNw6diMTCjaPwhjHEU9kQA)

Comment: I got how to do it from yours and @artcorpse's answer. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want, but only to a certain extent. The limiting factor is that `length` on an array is of type `number`, with no compile time knowledge of the actual length.

That being said, if you can deal with the fact that at the call site `TableHeader` and `TableRaw` are tuples, you can make it work, since for tuples `length` is `const`.

```js
type HeaderCol = string 
type TableHeader<P> = readonly HeaderCol[] & { length: P }
type TableData<P> = TableRow<P>[]
type TableRow<P> = readonly (string | number)[] & { length: P }

type NotAllNumbers<P extends number> = number extends P ? never : P;
function myFunction<P extends number>(header: TableHeader<P>, data: TableData<NotAllNumbers<P>>) {}

myFunction(['foo', 'bar'] as const, [[1, 2] as const]); // this compiles
myFunction(['foo', 'bar'] as const, [[1, 2, 3] as const]); // this doesn't compile because mismatching size.
myFunction(['foo', 'bar'], [[1, 2]]); // this doesn't compile because of dynamic size.
```

You can play with it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=79&pln=7&pc=92#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhCGATCAnAwgewDZQLxQGdgUBLAOwHMoBYAKFEigBV4AjLCOJVAHgAUAfHigoEiDGSwhYY1JiwBtALpQAZFADeUDpWAALAFxQ+UAL50G0FuwgAReMHj8h+axwBKGAO7PlF8FZsHt7OwqJIElJQABREpJRQAD5QZACuALasqACUymqa2hC6hsZmdP6MAHIYwACCWFiVGVkoBPxQEAAewEWIBCnNqC4Dmagd3b39JgD8KRAAbmNGfADcdABmqWQAxsAkElDpIABiW7v7ZO1dPWR9Iy0C0XqyKEZunC-OADRQiA7wbyCdn+PGqdQaTVGrWcAmymnMtDoR1OOz2EmiCgA5OsMBhMT9Max4ChMSp4P1thIiD8FAoAIw-ABMZIpVOASmyKygAHpuVB9CRWekwCQOAQkSczmiyBjsbj8VBCcTSVByVBKWRqVBaQyoIyfgBmFnqtkcrm8-l6QW-DAQAhkTHAE3C0XQLLbeCpAjQdKC9IObZWhIEEgALwgADoJSjzuisTi8QSiSSlDT6UylGaeXyBf1xHaHU7KS6OFB3Z7vVAMOtfiAyPBfdtCGHI3QgA).

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your time @artcorpse.